# Car will not start after sitting for three months - if I get it started will I be ok?

Tags: battery

I have a 2008 cheve impala that I left sitting (covered) for about three months.  It got a new battery just four months ago.  If I call AAA and get it started, will it be ill advised to drive the car like normal, or must I go to a mechanic?  That is, is there much of a risk that my car will not start again? Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: I've let my car sit through the winter on several occasions. Jump the battery and away we go. Of course, one thing you might want to do though is have the oil changed and generally check the car over for any problems. Make sure you run the car for a while or put the battery on a charger so you don't need another jump-start. This will also push the fluids around and make sure everything gets lubricated.

Answer (score 3):

So, you can get the AAA to start it, you should also check the oil level and tire pressures. You could also put the battery on charge overnight and if all else is well it should start from its own battery.

After that you can drive it, you may find the tires have "flat spots" due to being in the same position for so long, but they will normally work themselves out after a few miles or so.

Then after that it should be normal - it should not affect the reliability any further.

Comment: I once had exactly the same situation (caused by a medical emergency putting me in hospital for three months!). The only issue was a flat battery which prevented the car from starting. The (UK) AA guy who I called out checked the battery was still in good condition after the engine had been running for a few minutes, - and would have fitted a new battery there and then, if it had been required, rather than me having to go shopping for one.